# What to do when I'm unable to ask questions from my account?

Tags: support, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?  (the answer is here, in this post)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

I have a user account on Stack Overflow, but after logging in when I am going to ask questions, the website displays the message

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) to learn more.

What do I have to do in order to be able again to ask on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 12):

## Did you click on [the link](http://goo.gl/C1Kwu) and read the answer to that question?

#### If you're unwilling or unable to do that, we cannot help you. Sorry.

Comment: Your forehead seems a bit torn up from all the contact with brick walls lately. :p